# Perl function that takes a BLOCK as the second parameter?

Tags: perl, higher-order-functions, currying

I want to write a function whose first parameter is a description, and the second parameter is a code block.  I want the finished code to read like:

```
verify "description" { boolean-assertion-block };
```

I'm specifically looking to avoid the `sub` keyword.

I can put the description AFTER the code block, no problem:

```
sub verify (&$) { ... }
```

But when I reverse the prototype symbol order:

```
sub verify ($&) { ... }
```

Then I get an error message:

```
Type of arg 2 to main::verify must be sub {} (not anonymous hash ({})) at ...
```

Clearly, Perl has special handling for the first argument being a code block.

So, maybe I can make it a curried function?

```
sub verify ($) {
    my $message = shift;
    return sub (&) { . . . }
}
```

But then I get a syntax error between the description and the code block:

```
syntax error at ... near ""..." { "
```

I tried altering the calling syntax to try to help out the compiler:

```
test "...", { BLOCK };
test("..."){ BLOCK };
test("...")({ BLOCK });
( test "..." )({ BLOCK });
```

No joy.  Can Perl even do what I want to do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `(&)` prototype only has such niceness when used for the first argument in a sub. From `perldoc perlsub`:

> The interesting thing about "&" is that you can generate new syntax with it, provided it's in the initial position

One way to provide a similar level of niceness would be:

```perl
sub verify ($%) {
  my ( $message, %opts ) = @_;
  my $coderef = $opts{using};
  ...;
}

sub using (&) {
  my ( $coderef ) = @_;
  return ( using => $coderef );
}

# The `verify` sub accepts a name followed by a hash of options:
#
verify(
  "your message here",
  "using" => sub { ... },
);

# The `using` sub returns a two-element list that will satisfy
# that hash of options:
#
verify "your message here", using {
  ...;
};
```

If you desperately want to allow a syntax exactly like:

```perl
verify "description" { boolean-assertion-block };
```

... then it is still possible, but requires the dark arts. [Keyword::Simple](https://metacpan.org/pod/Keyword::Simple) is probably your best bet, but [Devel::Declare](https://metacpan.org/pod/Devel::Declare) and [Filter::Simple](https://metacpan.org/pod/Filter::Simple) are options.

Comment: Yeah...  I don't want it bad enough to resort to the Dark Arts...

Answer (score 4):

You can only use the block syntax if the `&` is the first thing in your prototype. From [perlsub](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlsub#Prototypes):

> An `&` requires an anonymous subroutine, which, if passed as the first argument, does not require the sub keyword or a subsequent comma

Other custom DSL such as in [Dancer2](https://metacpan.org/dist/Dancer2/view/lib/Dancer2/Manual/Keywords.pod#DSL-Keywords-manual) or [Mojolicious](https://metacpan.org/pod/Mojolicious::Lite#FUNCTIONS) typically use the `sub` keyword.

```perl
get '/foo' => sub {
  ...
};
```

[Plack::Builder](https://metacpan.org/pod/Plack::Builder) and [Web::Scraper](https://metacpan.org/pod/Web::Scraper) use blocks that return objects, which then can be nested.